# Textfield placeholder font creates issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uifont

[image]

I have added button as rightView to textfield.

I have set attributed text with custom font as placeholder text.

My textfield's placeholder and text font are different.

But when textfield's text is large and if I select whole text and remove
it then it not shows me placeholder text in its font. It shows in textfield's text font.

Detail Explanation :

- My Textfield's text font is : OpenSans Bold 18.0
- My Textfield's placeholder text font is : OpenSans 18.0 (Regular)

But when I select hole text (large) and delete text then it shows place holder text in: OpenSans Bold 18.0

But it should shows place holder text in: OpenSans 18.0 (Regular)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you will have to set the font every time the placeholder appears/disappears. Set the textfield delegate and add this code...

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let length = (textField.text?.characters.count)! + (string.characters.count - range.length)

    // If there is text in the text field
    if (length > 0) {
        // Set textfield font
        textField.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans Bold", size: 18)
    } else {
        // Set textfield placeholder font (or so it appears)
        textField.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans Regular", size: 18)
    }

    return true;
}
```

Obj-C:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{    
    // If there is text in the text field
    if (textField.text.length + (string.length - range.length) > 0) {
        // Set textfield font
        textField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans Bold" size:18];
    } else {
        // Set textfield placeholder font (or so it appears)
        textField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans Regular" size:18];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: @EricD: I just gave the code I used long before. Nevertheless I get your point. Answer updated.